# bzr send is the same as git push?

Tags: git, bazaar

send directive in Bazaar is the same as push in GIT?

Answer (score 2):

Why not read [Git for Bazaar users](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/survival/bzr-for-git-users.html)?

BTW, in Bazaar [push](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.1.16/en/user-reference/bzr_man.html#push) is not the same as [send](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.1.16/en/user-reference/bzr_man.html#send). The latter is a specialized bazaar command for sending changes via mail.

Comment: Actually the document you linked titled as "bzr for git users", not vice versa.